# read single byte as an unsigned byte

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

I have some a java server that I'm trying to get to play with a php script.

The format provides the number of bytes the message will take as an unsigned byte, and then the bytes that comprise the string.

here's my function with commentary

```
function read($socket, $readnum) {
    $endl = "<br>"; // It's running on apache

    // attempt to get the byte for the size
    $len = unpack("C",socket_read($socket, 1))[0];
    // this prints "after ", but $len does not print. $endl does
    echo "after " . $len . $endl;
    // obviously this fails because $len isn't in a valid state
    $msg = socket_read($socket, $len);
    // print the message for debugging?
    echo $len . " " . $msg;
    return $msg;
}
```

I'm not really a php guy, more of a Java guy, so I'm not sure how I should go about getting this length.

On @c0le2's request, I made the following edit

```
$lenarr = unpack("C",socket_read($socket, 1));
$len = $lenarr[0]; // line 81
```

Which gave the following error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in simple_connect.php on line 81
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unpack format string is actually like `code [repeater] [name]`, separated by forward slashes. For example, `Clength`. The output array will be associative and keyed by name, with repeated fields having a numeric suffix appended, starting at 1. E.g. the output keys for `C2length` will be `length1` and `length2`.

The documentation is not super-clear about this.

So when you don't specify any name, it just appends the numeric suffix, starting at 1. So the length you are looking for is `$lenarr[1]`.

But you should try this instead:

```
$v = unpack('Clength', "\x04");
var_export($v);  // array('length' => 4)
```

Here are some other examples:

```
unpack('C2length', "\x04\x03");
// array ( 'length1' => 4, 'length2' => 3, );

unpack('Clength/Cwidth', "\x04\x03");
// array ( 'length' => 4, 'width' => 3, );
```

Also, in php you can't generally use array-access notation on an expression--you need to use it on the variable directly.  So `functioncall()[0]` won't work, you need `$v = functioncall(); $v[0]`. This is a php wart.

Comment: +1, but since 5.4 you Can actually use dereferencing such as `f()[1]`

Comment: This is excellent and gave me just the information I needed to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a returned array like that. You'd do `$len[0]` after calling `unpack()`.

```
$len = unpack("C",socket_read($socket, 1));    
echo "after " . $len[0] . $endl;
```

Comment: That gives me "Undefined offset: 0 in simple_connect.php on line 81". I'll make an edit that shows my exact code. It occurs on the $len assignment.

Comment: @corsiKa: Do a `print_r($len);`, it will show what the key is (maybe it's [1] instead).